# API call not hitting WebAPI sub folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In our API we added child application `testapi.com/app`, however when we are making api calls it is not hitting child application and returns `404 error`. `HttpClient` base address points to `testapi.com/app`. When I try to make an api call `testapi.com/app/ping/{id}` it returns `404` but when I call `testapi.com/ping/{id}` it works fine. I have never done it before so I am not sure how to fix it. Tried adding sub-folder into `MapRoute` but it did not help.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "app/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("~/ping/{id}")]
    public JsonResult<TestListDTO[]> getPing(Guid id)
    {

       TestListDTO[] listDto = null;
       try
        {
           using (var ctx = new hubEntities())
           {
               if (id.Length == 18)
               {
                   var Logs = ctx.do_smth(id);
                   listDto = Mapper.Map<log_Result[], TestListDTO[]>(Logs.ToArray());
                }
               else if (id.Length == 36)
                {
                    Guid Idguid = new Guid(id);
                    var auditLogs = ctx.select_invoice_audit_log(securityUserId, accountIdOwner, null, invoiceIdguid);
                     var Logs = ctx.do_smth(id);
                    listDto = Mapper.Map<log_Result[], TestListDTO[]>(Logs.ToArray());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
       return Json(listDto);
    }
```

When I am tracing response which I get from API call is shows that: requestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri points to parent app and not child `http://testapi.com/ping/{id}.` 
Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: The sub app name does not need to be included in the route. You have a Route attribute, but your routing config does not enable attribute routing?

Comment: @CraigH sorry I am new to this, ok I editted: url: `"app/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, to `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, what do you mean by your routing config does not enable attribute routing?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not enable attribute routing then the conventional routing is used.
This means that your `[Route()]` attribute makes no difference, and the action hit will be based on:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

If you want to enable attribute routing, then you need to add this in your config:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

See [this link for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enabling-attribute-routing) on enabling attribute routing.

If you do not enable attribute routing then I expect something like this URL to work:

```
testapi.com/app/{YourControllerName}/getPing/{id}
```

The action name is basically the method name.
If you have enabled attribute routing then I would expect this URL to work:

```
testapi.com/app/ping/{id}
```

Hope this helps,
Craig.